# Collision work on pc emulator but not on android device

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have 2 objects with colliders. the sphere object("ball") should collide with the mesh("goal"):

- sphere collider
- mesh collider

they both non-kimetric.

i use the next code:

```
function OnCollisionEnter(theCollision : Collision){
    if(theCollision.gameObject.name == "goal" )
    {
        (tm.GetComponent(TextMesh) as TextMesh).text  =  "enter1";
        forceAmount.z=-1000;
        rb.AddForce(forceAmount);
    }
}
```

the code works perfect in the unity emulator
but when i build it to apk file and install on my android tablet its not works.

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity way of doing this is by setting the game objects a `Tag`. Use of tag is light weight and you can set tags from the editor and then use:

```
if (theCollision.gameObject.tag == "goal")
```

Comment: if its working in the editor with name then it should work on android either we use name or tag .

Comment: Time to debug! try outputting a log message inside the `OnCollisionEnter` and check if it is reached. Similarly inside the `if` statement also.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here in 2019, caused by me after deleting some unused tags. It was just a matter of restarting Unity.

Comment: Indeed it's a problem with tags as others mentioned already. I had deleted some tag and its slot remained there until I restarted Unity. Then the Android deployment started working (tags comparison was apparently only working on Editor after removing a tag). Thank you so much for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem -- collision detected in Editor but not in Android. I solved it by adjusting the radius from 0.5 to 20.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, it seems that there is some problem with Unity deploying the tags to android devices.

In my scenario, I had a RigidBody and a PreFab (set as a Trigger). In my code, I set the OnTriggerEnter to check for the tag of the item triggered and if it was the same as my PreFab tag, I would hide the item triggered.

This code works perfectly in my editor, however, it did not work when I deployed this solution to an android device.

After testing and modifying a couple things, what solved the issue was to use one of the pre-defined tags for my PreFab (instead of the custom one I was using "PickUpItem").

It seems to me that there is a problem in unity 5 sending custom tags to android devices, but for the preset tags, it works fine.

Comment: Could you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41926454/edit) to provide more details? I'm not an expert in the topic but your answer seems a bit too short to be a good quality answer. I also suggest you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem in 2019. After reading some comments, it seems that there's still a bug deploying tags to Android. I was using

```
if(col.gameObject.tag == "tagName")
```

But I changed it to check `gameObject.name` and it worked.